How to pass in an external-id when assuming an IAM role with the circleci/aws-cli orb
I have the following setup in AWS.
Account 1 contains an Identity Provider linked to my CircleCI organisation and an IAM role that can be assumed using sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
Account 2 contains another role which can be assumed by the role in account 1, provided the sts:ExternalId provided matches an expected value.
I've setup my CircleCI config.yml as follows:
version: "2.1"
orbs:
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@5.1.1
jobs:
  configure_role_arn:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/aws:2022.06
    steps:
      - checkout
      - aws-cli/setup:
          profile_name: initial-profile
          role_arn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXX:role/InitialRoleToAssume
      - aws-cli/role_arn_setup:
          profile_name: secondary-profile
          role_arn: arn:aws:iam::YYYYY:role/SecondaryRoleToAssume
          source_profile: initial-profile
      - run: aws sts get-caller-identity --profile initial-profile --region eu-west-2 
      - run: aws sts get-caller-identity --profile secondary-profile --region eu-west-2 

This works as expected if I remove the condition that expects the ExternalId, however, while that condition remains in place, my initial role can not assume the secondary role.
I would normally apply this when assuming the role as follows:
aws sts assume-role --external-id foobar

However, using this orb, I am no longer making that call explicitly.
Is there any way I can provide the external id when the secondary role is assumed?
Any advice appreciated.
Thanks
